# Getting the File Signature of a File through Lotus Script

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotusscript

Is there a way to get the file signature of a file inside a document? I tried checking the Embedded Object Class but it seems that there is no function for getting the file signature. Is there a way to get it just by using lotus script?

If not then I believe I'll need to maybe use a java class agent right? Can you provide a link that is doing this function or maybe can you guide me with some codes for this one. I am familiar with java but when it is being used in lotus notes agents I am not much familiar with the class being used.

Basically what I need to do is check the files in the documents and check if they are a valid file with the valid signature. Just checking the extension name is not enough as it might be renamed but the signature of the file is not valid so I'll need to confirm the file signature in checking. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write the file to file system and then you can read the file from there. Use a temp directory and delete every file after usage.

Look [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_EXAMPLES_EMBEDDEDOBJECTS_PROPERTY_RTITEM.html) for code to write attachments to file system as a starting point. Property `EmbeddedObjects` is available for documents too in case you want to analyse all attachments of a document.

You can accomplish the same in Java. Just look for Java classes in Language cross-reference in  documentation.

Comment: Hi Knut, I have a question how would I identify even after extracting it to a file path and reading it. I get understand that I can read the file, but how would I know whether it is a real excel file or exe file or html file and so on? Basically my problem now is that I can get the file using lotus script but I am not sure how to identify them by not just relying on the extension file name but the on what signature the file has. Thanks. I hope you got my problem? Thanks

Comment: Read the file binary byte by byte and compare first bytes to known file signatures like listed here http://www.filesignatures.net/index.php?page=all

Comment: Hmm, I looked into it Knut. I know this is a silly question but let me ask.. I am not sure how to read the file binary byte to byte.. I know using OPEN whenever reading a file but it will read the data inside it right? Can you give me a link on how to do it? I tried researching it but I am confused.. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look here http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/LSAZ_BINARY_FILES.html

Comment: ok sure, thanks Knut let me analyze them too and how I can implement this solution. Thanks a lot. I might ask some more questions so I'll accept your answer once it's done.

Comment: Good luck. Just ask if you can't get forward with something.

Comment: Could you get it to work or do you need some assistance?

Comment: Hi Knut, Actually we used java codes in order to read the file. It is written in the script library and is just being called to check the signature file. Thanks a lot for your help!